# Why need to strip changes from default branch while pushing that changes from another branch

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, tortoisehg

I did changes in default branch and created a patch. Then I have created my own branch from default. I exported changes patch from default and imported it to my own branch. While pushing changes from my branch using tortoise hg tool in ubuntu , it shows me only the changes which i imported from default. But when I pushed the changes from my branch, all drafts in default branch also get pushed. Why its so?

**Only those drafts which having parent same as hash from where i have created my branch is pushed.**

**for example**
lets say, I have  public change A in default .
I have created my draft B over A in default
Then I have created my draft C over A in default.Means C and B both have A is parent.
I pulled latest code from default. Now D is latest public.
I created my branch from D and also re-based B over D.
Then exported B. and imported in my branch.
I have pushed B from my branch. While pushing it shows me only one B draft.

Issue is C draft in default is also get pushed.

Please help me on this

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSKiu.png)

Comment: Please add the example log -G output (including phase information) of what you talk about... it would make it MUCH easier to follow

Comment: I have attached image to question

Answer (score 0):

In Mercurial, when you push, you by default push the entire structure of the repository tree. If this would create a new head in a branch on the remote repository, Mercurial will abort the push, unless `hg push --force` is specified. (It is recommended not to force the push without a good reason, because multiple heads on a branch will likely cause a confusion.)

If you have TortoiseHg, you can display the revisions in the draft state by typing `draft()` in the filter box and pressing ENTER. (If you don't see one, click on the "[Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiyJ1.png)" icon.) From the command line, you can show the same using the command `hg log --rev draft()`.

To push a specific revision, you can use the command `hg push --rev RevisionNumberOrHash` (such as `hg push --rev 123`). Alternately, you can mark the unwanted revision as secret. To do this, use the command `hg phase --rev RevisionNumberOrHash --secret --force`; in TortoiseHg, right-click on the revision and select "Change phase to" -> "Secret". Secret revisions will not be pushed unless you specifically select them for pushing, or unless you change them back to the draft state. (Important: if a revision is secret, so are all its descendants.)